# Store logged in user for that session

Tags: c#, winforms

We all know how easy it is to create a static class in c# and use that to reference that in a app but its a possible to make a variable that can change I am wanting to track the user id of a user once they have logged in in something like this

```
public static class MyUser
{
   public static int UserId {get;set;}
}
```

Is that an acceptable way of doing it will it keep durig the context of my program I only want to set it on the login form then reference it on the rest.

Comment: You could have a user class, and have a static class with a List<User> field, that you would add your users to

Comment: Your app will have one `MyUser` in memory and if you set `UserId` during login, it will have that value until you close the application. In a desktop app that should be fine. In a web, it will not be.

Comment: @CodingYoshi your approach sounds sound, but  how do i pass that value from form to form without creating a new instance of the class myuser?

Comment: @davidbuc you do not need to pass it around. Simply access it like this: `MyUser.UserId` wherever you need.

Comment: And please don't call your class MyUser... call it LoggedInUser or some other more meaningful name than MyUser.